# on-premise SSL/TLS Cert testing tool (100's of sites)

Tags: automated-testing, security-testing

Has anyone found a good way to on-premise test SSL/TLS certs for many (100's) of sites on a regular basis?

The usecase is websites setup both internally, and with VPN tunnels to many customers, as such no internet-facing presence.

Things to check:

- does the cert match the dns/url name
- are all the intermediate certs accounted for
- is it expired
- is it signed by a trusted thirdparty site (commonly recognized by browsers)

bonus for:

- are there weak ciphers allowed

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any tools that do this pre-made.  But a loop and a list of your cert files in a shell with openssl installed should do it.  To verify the full chain, check out the `openssl verify` command.  Something like this should work:

```
openssl verify -CAfile root_cert.pem -untrusted intermediate_cert.pem user_cert.pem
```

You can also add multiple intermediate certs as well.  For each one just add another `-untrusted` flag for the cert.

There are a few specific pre-made tools that will verify supported ciphers.  Check out [`sslscan` to test ciphers](https://github.com/rbsec/sslscan).

Again, with a few loops in your preferred shell (bash for example), you can achieve a similar effect. Just make sure you have the openssl client installed and run something like:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -cipher <test_cipher> -connect <your_endpoint>:<tls_port>
```